# How to Handle the Alert Pop Up

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am working on the Web Application, In that Application user need to send the values into

the Search Text Box, then user need to click on the Search Button, If the Value are

avilable in the db, then that value will be display on the another Text Box, If that value

in not in the db, Then Alert Pop up is Displaying on the screen, At that i am using below

code, But it is not working fine.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id(APL.MT_ET_Search_Btn_ID)).isEnabled())                                  
{
    driver.findElement(By.id(APL.MT_ET_Search_Btn_ID)).click();                                 
    System.out.println("Clicked on the Search Button for the Text box");

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //Handling the Code

    String page = driver.getTitle();

    System.out.println(page); 

    if(page.equals("No Recipients found"));
    {
        System.out.println("No Recipients found");
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        System.out.println("Handling the Pop Up");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the second if, remove the semicolon and it will be better.

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id(APL.MT_ET_Search_Btn_ID)).isEnabled())                                  
{
    driver.findElement(By.id(APL.MT_ET_Search_Btn_ID)).click();                                 
    System.out.println("Clicked on the Search Button for the Text box");

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //Handling the Code

    String page = driver.getTitle();

    System.out.println(page); 

    if(page.equals("No Recipients found")) //#############HERE
    {
        System.out.println("No Recipients found");
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        System.out.println("Handling the Pop Up");
    }
}
```

Anyway if you please tell us WHY is not working I can check if there can be other problems.